# Bootable usb stick created in windows won`t show in startup manager in mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, install

My MacBook Pro (Early 2015) won't boot any more;  it boots into a flashing screen with a folder with question mark.

I downloaded a High Sierra DMG and created a bootable USB using both Transmac and PowerISO (in Windows 10) and none of them boots the system.

What should I do? Am i doing something wrong here?

EDIT:
I have tried from a ubuntu using dmg2img and then making a bootable stick by dd and it didn`t work either.

Comment: Have you tried the Recovery options?  Hold `Cmd-R` or `Opt-Cmd-R`  High Sierra isn't distributed as a DMG.  I'm assuming you got this via a Torrent or other sharing method?  Avoid this.  Try the recovery options first, then go from there.

Comment: i don`t have a stable wifi network thats not an option for me.

Comment: What about holding `Opt` and booting from the Recovery partition?  If WiFi isn't stable, how did you download the DMG?

Comment: i dont have a reocovery partition i think. nothing shows up when i hold opt button.
i downloaded the DMG file from a server near my location.

Comment: Your best bet is to get to a place with with decent Internet and perform recovery.  Not knowing how that DMG was created (since it doesn't come that way) it's impossible for us to walk you through the install.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of any possible way to create a bootable USB drive on Windows, but if you have access to a Mac you can use [Install Disk Creator](https://macdaddy.io/install-disk-creator/) to easily create the boot device.

- Download Install Disk Creator
- Download MacOS High Sierra from App Store
- Open Install Disk Creator
- Select your USB drive
- Select the MacOS installer
- Click Create installer